# Unit Testing in .NET: How to Mock Entity Data Provider

Tags: unit-testing, entity-framework, mocking

Does anyone know whether there's a way to mock Entity Data Provider so Unit Tests don't hit the live data? I found this blog but it seems the project hasn't been released:

http://www.chrisdoesdev.com/index.php/archives/62

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mattwar has a [great article on his blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/mattwar/archive/2008/05/04/mocks-nix-an-extensible-linq-to-sql-datacontext.aspx) about mocking up LinqtoSql with reflection -- perhaps you can use that as a starting point?

Answer (score 0):

I would be interested to know this myself.  I don't think that it's possible, because one of the things that got the Agile/Alt.Net community in a tizzy about the Entity Framework was this very problem of the lack of persistence ignorance.